# Algebraic manipulation of trigonometric Taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

There are a number of standard identities that are simple to understand for trigonometric functions (like $\sin(x+2π) = \sin(x)$ or $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$), but when these same identities are stated in terms of the function's Taylor expansion they are anything but obvious. I am wondering how you could prove the above (or other) identities true if you were only working with the Taylor series expansions algebraically. That is, are there methods for proving such identities of the functions ?

$$\sin x=x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}  ...$$

$$\cos x =1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} ...$$

without relying on their equivalence to cos and sin. While any identity proofs are appreciated I am primarily interested in those relating to pi.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe next step is to look at derivatives, differential equations and functional equations.

Answer (score 2):

*Comment* for $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x) = 1$.

Start from
$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} x^{2k}
$$
Then compute the series for $\cos^2(x)$
using the Cauchy product to get
$$
\cos^2(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k x^{2k},
$$
where
$$
A_k = \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j)!}\;\frac{(-1)^{k-j}}{(2(k-j))!} .
$$
So we have to do some combinatorics to get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j)!}\;\frac{(-1)^{k-j}}{(2(k-j))!}
= \frac{(-1)^k 4^k}{2 (2k)!}
$$

Then we need to do $\sin^2(x)$ similarly, and add them.  All terms cancel except the constant term $1$.

Answer (score 2):

A general method for this context is to use the identities

$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i},\quad
\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2,\quad
e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $$

which agrees with the power series expansions you exhibited.

For example, the trigonometric identity

$$ \sin(2y)\sin(2z) = \sin(y+z)^2 - \sin(y-z)^2 $$

can be written as

$$ \frac{Y^2-Y^{-2}}{2i}\frac{Z^2-Z^{-2}}{2i} =
  \frac{(YZ-(YZ)^{-1})^2}{-4} - \frac{(Y/Z-(Y/Z)^{-1})^2}{-4} $$

using the notation $\,Y:=e^{iy}, Z:=e^{iz}.\,$

It is easily verified with elementary algebra without the power series
expansion of $\,\sin.\,$